# AttributeError: __enter__ using with statement SqlAlchemy session

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I'm getting this `AttributeError: __enter__` when I try to use SQLAalchemy session like in this [guide](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html).

My code:

```py
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=False, bind=engine))
    
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.session_scope = session_scope

    def something_with_session(self):

        with self.session_scope as session:  # <-- error
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: Can you post the full traceback to show where the problem is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to call the function to get the context

```
with self.session_scope() as session:
    ...
```

Answer (score 11):

For those used to SQLAlchemy 1.4 way of running the session construction / close process via context manager like so:

```
with Session() as session:
    # Do something
```

If you are getting `AttributeError: __enter__`, check that the SQLAlchemy version in your environment is really `SQLAlchemy>=1.4`. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70738923/8929855).

Comment: Up voted for the ref  to version compatibility.  Was running 1.3 on an old environment and wondering why it wasn't working.