# SQLAlchemy object Session AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy session not working when I use it inside a with statement. It should work, since the `sessionmaker` returns a `Session` object that according to the [source code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py) does have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. I checked and I am in using the latest version (SQLAlchemy==1.3.22).

Code used to pinpoint the error:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(
    'sqlite:////devdb/sqlite.db',
    echo=True
)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

with Session() as session:
    print('it worked!')
```

The Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    with Session() as session:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I also tried my own class, just to test it, and same error occurred:

```py
class MySessionMaker(sessionmaker):
    def __init__(self, bind):
        super().__init__(bind=bind)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self()

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback):
        self.close()



Session = MySessionMaker(bind=engine)
```

I could not find anything online regarding this error, have anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: One case might be that you've assigned the built-in `Session` to something else in your code. Please check that.

Comment: the code I posted is the complete file that gives me the error

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @SpencerBoucher it was an issue with some module's version, i just recreated the env with the latest stable versions and it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receiving "AttributeError: \_\_enter\_\_" when using SQLAlchemy Session as context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66554373/receiving-attributeerror-enter-when-using-sqlalchemy-session-as-context-m)